# pip install fails on git repository on windows 10

Tags: git, github, pip, python-import

I'm trying to install dm_control from github on windows 10.
Direct install from the repository using the command line

```
pip install git+git://github.com/deepmind/dm_control.git
```

fails because of ***ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'dm_control'*** on line

```
from dm_control.autowrap import binding_generator
```

but the modules clearly exist in the repository structure. I get the same error if I download the repository and pip install from a local directory.
However if I use the editable flag on the local download then the package installs successfully ?

```
pip install -e C:\Download\dm_control
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here and how I can directly install from the repository with the first command line call.

Comment: It feels like you forgot to show the rest of the output of `pip install git+git://github.com/deepmind/dm_control.git`. Can  you just show the entire run from `C:\whatever> pip install ...` to getting back to an empty prompt? Also, what happens if you use pipenv rather than pip? (because its good practice to never install things globally if you can help it and pipenv is a godsend)

Comment: Well, if -e works locally, it should also work remotely with `pip install -e git+git://github.com/deepmind/dm_control.git`... right?

Comment: Unfortunately not ! editable flag does not work from git repository, only when I install from a local directory containing a downloaded copy of the repository

Comment: Also same behavior from pipenv